# Looking for passportjs-local simple example using MEAN only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, mean

I am looking for a very simple example for using Passportjs (Local api) in my MEAN application. I took a reference from [one example on github](https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo). There they have used jade to render the page after authentication. But I just want to use my `home.html` to show home page after authentication.

I have searched many example but in all they are using either jade or ejs. I don't want to use any engine to render the home page.

If anyone can provide a very simple example just using MEAN that would be a great help.

I don't want to use `jade` or `ejs`. Just simple html to render page.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a route similar to this:

```
app.route("/login")
    .post(passport.authenticate("local"), function (req, res) {
        res.json(req.user);
    });
```

Then call that as an post call from the function you bind the form to in angular, you don't need to use jade/pug/ejs or any of it.  You can simply use express as an API server. Just have angular redirect to the route you want after the successful return of the authentication (you should get a user object back)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll try this and get back to you if I stuck. Hope you don't mind.